# Can't insert into DB

Tags: php, mysql, string, forms

Not sure why, I can't process the PHP.  The script connects fine but I can't insert the entries in to the DB:

```
   $fullname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
   $title = mysql_escape_string($_POST['title']);
   $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
   $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);



    $insert = "INSERT INTO human_network (Employee_id, Name, Title, Email, Username, 
    Password, Date_time_created)
    VALUES ('".$eid."','".$_POST['name']."', '".$title."', '".$email."', 
    '".$uname."', '".$password."', '".$createddate."')";
     $add_member = mysql_query($insert);
```

Upon checking further this is the error I get:

Invalid query: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) via `$_POST['name']`, which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql driver to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements). If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: if (!$add_member) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: Don't worry i am using test versions.  Anything you notice regarding the code?

Comment: @AAA: note that Dagon's snippet should be replaced with proper error handling before putting the code into production. Only admins should see [database errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2), and [`or die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) isn't suitable when outputting HTML.

Comment: what about $createddate? This is not set before..

Comment: Note also that you don't need to concatenate variables when using double quoted strings. You can interpolate them directly into the string, which is more readable as SQL: `"INSERT INTO human_network (Employee_id, Name, Title, Email, Username, 
    Password, Date_time_created)
    VALUES ('$eid','$fullname', '$title', '$email', 
    '$uname', '$password', '$createddate')"`

Comment: @Dagon i am getting this: Invalid query: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @AAA what code are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: i am using <?php include("connect.php");?>

Comment: @AAA you need to check what is inside connect.php

Comment: Is this a newly created database, you may need to grant permissions to the www-data user account for that database. Generally this is not done by default when creating a new database and must be done manually for non-admin accounts. Additionally, it looks like you may have left out the password, which I am assuming it is not blank.

Comment: For reference: [§5.5. MySQL User Account Management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of the error: check your mysql user permissions. user `www-data` seems not to have the permission to execute `INSERT`

Comment: That or he should be using a password, which it appears he is not.

Comment: I think the server is allowed to execute the insert.

Comment: @AAA Inserts are performed under a user account created in the database. That user account must have insert permissions granted for the database in question in order for it to work. In this case you are trying to connect and insert data using the `www-data` user.